# Angular2 Form Validation not works on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, angular2-forms, angular-validation

I'm using angular2-seed, with form validation. My project works well, but not on safari. When I go to the page has form validation, I get this error: `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: No locale data has been provided for this object yet.`. This error just happen on old safari (<9.1.3), and works normally on modern safari 10.
[image]